# How do I connect a web view in the storyboard to an outlet in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, webview, xcode5, outlet

For some reason, I am not able to ctrl drag the web view I am trying to create into the .h file. I typed the code into the .h file. Now, I need to know how to connect the web view with the outlet I created. Most of the suggestions I have seen tell me to use the .xib file, however, I do not have a .xib. All of this is done in Xcode 5. As of now, if I try to run the app, the web view simply shows up as a plain white screen. If anyone has any ideas on how to connect the outlet with my web view, I would really appreciate it.

edit:
Here is the code I used to make the outlet, is it incorrect?

```
IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
```

Comment: Did you set the custom class to your UIView or UIViewController subclass in the Storyboard?

Comment: @Jonathan, it looks like it is set on UIWebView right now. I clicked the drop down, but UIWebView is the only option.

Comment: I mean, have you set the UIViewController's Custom class in storyboard to your UIViewController subclass, not the UIWebView.

Comment: @Jonathan, when I select the view controller it has gray text in the custom class box which says UIViewController, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: That's it. All you need to do is type in your UIViewController subclass name. e.g. InitialViewController Then, make the connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange, it shouldn't at all do this. but anyway, since you wrote the code, I believe you can now open the connections inspector (( the last tab of the inspectors window )) and ctrl drag from you connections inspector to your webview (( or vice-versa, i don't quite remember )). However, if this doesn't work, then you have a serious problem with your xcode buddy, try to solve it.

Comment: I've tried that. The outlet I made doesn't appear there. Any outlet I try to drag selects the whole view, not just the web view.